# PHP Laravel return to view null variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have method to get word form searchbar and query in db,then return to view

but it show empty table although i check for null variable

this is controller code

```
<?php

    public function getSearch($title) {
            $words = Word::where('title', $title)->first();
            if (empty($words)) {

                abort(404);
            }
            return view('dict.index', compact('words'));

        }
```

here is view code

```
<?php

    foreach ($words as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['meaning'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $row['rate']; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20">';
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: i suggest why it my view has empty table because
if (empty($words)) {

   abort(404);
  }
not enter

Comment: i suspect because i use ->first(); ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. For starters your query will always return one element, while I supose you want all results from the query. You should use the get function to [`get`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) all rows from the query.

Using [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on an eloquent collection will never return `false` because you will always receive an eloquent object or a collection. to check if your collection has any values, you can use the [`isEmpty`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-isempty) function.

The result should be something like this:

```
<?php

    public function getSearch($title) {
            $words = Word::where('title', $title)->get();
            if ($words->isEmpty()) {
                abort(404);
            }

            return view('dict.index', compact('words'));
        }
```

**For the view:**

Because you are using eloquent, you don't have to use array keys to select the values, you should use object properties. Like so:

```
<?php

    foreach ($words as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->title . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->meaning . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $row->rate; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20">';
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: ok when i change to get it OK,
but i confuse between first and get 
first return one element, wat it mean and when i should use first();

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jerodev's answer, a more elegant way to composer your view would be to use the blade syntax.

```
@foreach($words as $word)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $word->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $word->meaning }}</td>
    <td>
    @for($i=0; $i<$word->rate; $i++)
        <img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20" />
    @endfor
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Remember to add the `.blade` suffix to your views. For example, `dict.index.blade.php`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade